# Pinned view not saved in Dynamics CRM mobile client

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-mobile

Dynamics 365 online - We are facing one problem with the  Dynamics CRM mobile client. When a user pinned a view of an entity, it appears as required on that particular mobile device as and when user logins into the same device. But, when the user logs in again with the same credentials in a different device or opens the Dynamics CRM in Tablet mode in the browser, the pinned view gets removed from the "Home". It seems like Microsoft is managing it at the device level. We would like to manage it at the user level, like user's personal settings and that should be applicable wherever the same user logins anywhere on any devices. Please advise.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

User has to [reconfigure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/mobile-app/dynamics-365-phones-tablets-users-guide#reconfigure-the-app) the app to see the changes in effect.

> Reconfiguring deletes all data and metadata from the cache, though you
>   shouldn't rely on this as a security measure.
>
> If you sign out of one organization and sign in to another, and then
>   use the Reconfigure option on the organization you signed in to, your
>   metadata will still remain for the organization you signed out of. To
>   remove your metadata from the organization you signed out of, you’ll
>   need to sign in to it and use the Reconfigure option there, as well.
>
> Here's how to do it:
>   Tap Dynamics 365 ellipsis (3 dots).
>   Tap User
>   Information.
>   Tap Reconfigure.